# Can Shiny use inputs that are blocked by quotes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, stringr

I'm working on a relatively simple shiny app where I want the user to type several free-text keywords, have the Shiny server code query the table and create/refresh "trend" a new/existing column, and then graph that series on a facet grid.

The app itself runs and shows the graphs, but it doesn't appear to be picking up any data.  The graphs currently show all observations flatlining at zero.

My running theory (may not be the real fault) is that the reactive inputs are not found within the stringr function. Since they aren't found the "trend" frequency is at 0 because nothing / word count would be 0 for everything. Any idea on how to escape that?

Shiny UI

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(titlePanel("Enron Email Analysis"),
     sidebarLayout(position = "lef",
            sidebarPanel( h4("What was Enron saying as the ship started sinking?"), 
                          p("Find out now - search for the relative frequency of keywords over three years of enron emails."),
                          p("To view where Enron employees were communicating uncertainty over time use the recommended keywords."),
                          br(),
                          textInput("key1","Keywords","?"),
                          textInput("key2","","maybe"),
                          textInput("key3","","think"),
                          textInput("key4","","believe"),
                          textInput("key5","","don't know"),
                          textInput("key6","","could"),
                          textInput("key7","","might"),
                          textInput("key7","","uncertain")
                         ),
            mainPanel("", plotOutput("enrongraph")))))
```

Shiny Server

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
    output$enrongraph <- renderPlot({

    ## loading data ##
       enronpool <-read.csv("/Users/michaelcata/Documents/Enron/Enronapp/EnronBagofWordsInternal.csv",check.names=FALSE)

    ## changing the column names ##
       setnames(enronpool,"concat(subject,\" \",body)","text")

    ## changing format ##
       enronpool$text <- as.character(enronpool$text)

    ## creating rank for hierarchy ##
       enronpool$hier <- factor(enronpool$hier, levels = c("CEO", "President", "Vice President", "In-House Lawyer", "Managing Director", "Director", "Manager", "Trader", "Employee", "N/A"))

    ## creating rank for message direction ##
       enronpool$direct <- factor(enronpool$direct, levels = c("Above","Peer","Below"))

   ## creating word frequency trend -- here's where the issue may be ##
       enronpool$trend <- (str_count(enronpool$text, " input$key1 | input$key2 | input$key3 | input$key4 | input$key5 | input$key6 | input$key7"))/str_count(enronpool$text,"\\S+")

   ## plot ##

       ggplot(enronpool, aes(newdate,trend))+facet_grid(direct~hier, scales="fixed")+geom_smooth(aes(group=hier, color=hier),breaks=FALSE)+theme(legend.position="none")+labs(x='Mid 1998 - Late 2002',y="Uncertainty in Tone")+geom_rect(aes(xmin='2001-08-22', xmax='2001-09-02', ymin=0,ymax=+Inf), alpha=0.2, fill="grey")+ylim(-.01,.05))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the problem or not, but you're not supposed to make a call to `renderPlot` inside `output$enrongraph <- renderPlot({...})`.  Just make the `ggplot(...)` call the last value in the outer `renderPlot` and remove the second `renderPlot`.

Like this:

```
output$enrongraph <- renderPlot({
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ggplot(enronpool, ...)
})
```

Comment: Hey @daattali thanks for the note - mistake on my code entry into SO - I've corrected.